# Equivalent of x:Type in UWP

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, uwp, markup-extensions

I have this class:

```
public class EditorKey
{
    public Type TargetType { get; set; }
    public DataTemplate Template { get; set; }
}
```

Now, I want to create an instance of this class in XAML. Since in UWP we don't have the x:Type markup extension, I'm specifying the type directly as a string, with the correct prefix with `TargetType="model:Customer"`

```
<Page
    x:Class="App8.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:model="using:App8"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <ContentControl>
        <model:EditorKey TargetType="model:Customer" />
    </ContentControl>

</Page>
```

Running this, I get a runtime exception:

Failed to create a 'App8.EditorKey' from the text 'model:Customer'.

How can I map the string to the actual Type?

Comment: Not sure if that's what you asking, but if you need to specify the `model` XML namespace you do that by adding `xmlns:model="using:Namespace.Of.Your.Model"` to (usually) the root element of XAML.

Comment: Please, check the updated question. Now it's pretty clear what I'm asking. Thank you :)

Comment: What about using `Namespace.Of.Your.Model.Customer` (classic C# full name of a type) instead of using the XML namespace? Does that work?

Comment: It doesn't work unless you also specify the assembly "Namespace.Of.Your.Model.Customer, Assembly". It's really verbose :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual way of doing it in UWP is to simply supply the reference as a string:

```xml
<model:EditorKey TargetType="model:Customer" />
```

If this doesn't work, try specifying the full namespace, rather than defining an `xmlns`.

Example:

```xml
<model:EditorKey TargetType="App8.Customer" />
```

---

Note: As of time of writing, there's an issue where the above will crash in Release mode. As a workaround, you can create a Markup extension:

```cs
[MarkupExtensionReturnType(ReturnType = typeof(Type))]
public sealed class TypeExtension : MarkupExtension
{
    public Type Type { get; set; }

    /// <inheritdoc/>
    protected override object ProvideValue() => Type;
}
```

And use it like so:

```xml
<model:EditorKey TargetType="{local:Type Type='App8.Customer'"/>
```